# Structuring a Python Project of a Collection of Scripts

Tags: python

So I've scoured the web to try and find answer for this but can't seem to find any good information on this so thought I would pose the question here. I am a fairly knowledgeable with Python code but not so much when it comes to project structure/creation/best practices/etc. (I guess irrelevant to question so I'll get to it...)

So I have a Python project, that is essentially a large collection of scripts that utilize a few modules. I am having a hard time understanding how to structure this package.

So I'll give an overlay of how it is structured now.

```
python-project/
├── docs
├── modules
│   ├── module1.py
│   ├── module2.py
│   ├── ...
├── scripts
│   ├── scriptsfolder1
|   |  ├── script1
|   |  ├── script1-2
│   ├── scriptsfolder2
|   |  ├── script2
|   |  ├── script2-2
└── setup.py
```

So I guess I'm just trying to understanding whether or not the Python project format is required for a project like this or whether I'm just to maintain a set of isolated scripts in the same directory as my module. How do I make this an installable package?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: That looks fairly decent at first glance, but it's hard to say without knowing that scripts and modules use which other scripts and modules.

Comment: So the scripts are isolated completely from one another, run independently. The only commonality is that they share modules1/2/...